# Cell background color changes cell layout

Tags: notebooks, formatting

When I change the background color of a cell like in

[image]

the colored cells become slightly indented and their line spacing is increased.

How can I change the cell background color while keeping the other cell layout elements fixed?

Comment: Robinaut, I see you Accepted my answer.  Thanks; I'm glad it was helpful.  I notice that you did not vote for it however; are you aware that you can both vote for *and* Accept an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the Option Inspector and set `CellFrameMargins` to `0` you will get the closer spacing.
You could do this at the Style Sheet level to avoid repetition of effort.

I don't know if there is a cleaner or simpler way.

[image: Mathematica graphics]